# Show MySQL invalid triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm working with MySQL database, and i have to find all invalid triggers.
How can i check if some triggers are broken?

I have to get the equivalent of this oracle query for MySQL database:

```
select * from user_objects where object_type='TRIGGER' and status ='INVALID'
```

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Triggers table does not have a status column.
There is no way to know if a trigger is broken, till it is fired.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.TRIGGERS;
```